# Value Search from Dictionary via User Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have written the following code for getting an output of the various districts located in the given city and their respective postal codes. I want my code to be able to receive input from the user (District Name) and output the City in which it is located and it's postal code. If the user inputs a postal code they'll get the respective district(s).

```
zipcode = {"Trap City":{"C District": 100, "D District": 103, 
       "E District": 104, "S District": 105}, 
       "Zap City":{"R District": 200, "D District": 201},
       "Los City": {"X District": 207, "Y District": 208}}


district=input('Enter your district: ')

for city in zipcode:
    if district in city:
        print(city,zipcode[city][district])





d_district = {k2: (k1, v2) for k1, v1 in zipcode.items() for k2, v2 in 
v1.items()}

print(d_district)

{'C District': ('Trap City', 100),
'D District': ('Zap City', 201),
'E District': ('Trap City', 104),
'R District': ('Zap City', 200),
'S District': ('Trap City', 105),
'X District': ('Los City', 207),
'Y District': ('Los City', 208)}

d_code = {v2: k2 for k1, v1 in zipcode.items() for k2, v2 in 
v1.items()}

print(d_code)

{100: 'C District',
103: 'D District',
104: 'E District',
105: 'S District',
200: 'R District',
201: 'D District',
207: 'X District',
208: 'Y District'}
```

Output:

```
Enter your district: X District
{'C District': ('Trap City', 100), 'D District': ('Zap City', 201), 'E 
District': ('Trap City', 104), 'S District': ('Trap City', 105), 'R 
District': ('Zap City', 200), 'X District': ('Los City', 207), 'Y 
District': ('Los City', 208)}
{100: 'C District', 103: 'D District', 104: 'E District', 105: 'S 
District', 200: 'R District', 201: 'D District', 207: 'X District', 
208: 'Y District'}
>>>
```

The program instead just dumps all the information instead of searching for the value?

Comment: Your input is ambiguous. `D District` appears in both `Trap City` and `Zap City`. Which does it *really* appear in? Or what do you want as your *desired output* in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The program does only execute the two print statements `print(d_district)` and `print(d_code)`, where you actually just dump the contents of the `zipcode` dictionary. Your first print statement is never reached, as the condition never gets fulfilled. You have to compare to the value and not the key of the dictionary.

For the reversed case, you can check if the string entered by the user is numeric, and if this is the case, you just search for the zipcode in the same manner.

```
mydistrict=input('Enter your district: ')

if mydistrict.strip().isnumeric():
    for city in zipcode:
        for district in zipcode[city]:
            if zipcode[city][district] == int(mydistrict.strip()):
                print(city,zipcode[city][district])
else:
    for city in zipcode:
        if mydistrict in zipcode[city]:
            print(city,zipcode[city][mydistrict])
```

Comment: Now how do I get the code to output the district and city located if the user inputs a postal code?

Answer (score 0):

Googled the results. Dont know python. Might be working just for this example: Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

 def get_dis_cit():
    zpdf =pd.DataFrame(zipcode)#zipdataframe
    inpt =  input('Enter your zip code or your district: ')

    if inpt.isnumeric(): 
        zpdf = zpdf==int(inpt)
        district = list(zpdf.columns[zpdf.any()]) + list(zpdf.index[zpdf.T.any()])
        return dict(zip(["city","District"], district))
    else:
       district = re.search('\\b'+inpt+"[^']*",str(zipcode),re.I).group()
       city = list(zpdf.loc[district].dropna().index)
       return dict(zip(city, [district] * len(city)))
```

### Results

```
get_dis_cit()

Enter your zip code or your district: 100
Out[71]: {'city': 'Trap City', 'District': 'C District'}

get_dis_cit()

Enter your zip code or your district: 200
Out[72]: {'city': 'Zap City', 'District': 'R District'}

get_dis_cit()

Enter your zip code or your district: r dist
Out[73]: {'city': 'Zap City', 'District': 'R District'}

get_dis_cit()

Enter your zip code or your district: Y DISTRICT
Out[74]: {'city': 'Los City', 'District': 'Y District'}

get_dis_cit()

Enter your zip code or your district: D dist
Out[75]: {'Trap City': 'D District', 'Zap City': 'D District'}
```

### Data:

```
zipcode = {
    "Trap City": {
        "C District": 100,
        "D District": 103,
        "E District": 104,
        "S District": 105
    },
    "Zap City": {
        "R District": 200,
        "D District": 201
    },
    "Los City": {
        "X District": 207,
        "Y District": 208
    }
}
```