# Referencing and Printing Values from Dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My code below finds which city the district entered by the user is located in and it's postal code. I have put my data into a dictionary and I want to know how I can modify the code to receive a postal code from the user and output the district and the city it is located in.

Code:

```
zipcode = {
    "Trap City": {
        "C District": 100,
        "D District": 103,
        "E District": 104,
        "S District": 105
    },
    "Zap City": {
        "R District": 200,
        "D District": 201
    },
    "Los City": {
        "X District": 207,
        "Y District": 208
    }
}

district=input('Enter your district: ')

for city in zipcode:
    if district in zipcode[city]:
        print(city,zipcode[city][district])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value Search from Dictionary via User Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301426/value-search-from-dictionary-via-user-input)

Answer (score 0):

With 'zipcode[city]' you get the whole dictionary. I guess the user is supposed to enter the District as String?

```
for city in zipcode:
    if district in list(zipcode[city].keys()):
        print(city,zipcode[city][district])
```

**list(zipcode[city].keys())** gives you all keys from the city-dictionary against which you can check for the district.
For Python 2.x it'd just be **zipcode[city].keys()** to get the list.

Comment: Since D District exists in two of your dictionaries I guess you actually don't want the user to input a string but an integer like **103**, in that case you'd have to check against **list(zipcode[city].values())**

Answer (score 0):

Just transform `zipcode` with dict comprehension so that it's indexed by zipcodes instead:

```
{z: (c, d) for c, i in zipcode.items() for d, z in i.items()}
```

This outputs:

```
{100: ('Trap City', 'C District'), 103: ('Trap City', 'D District'), 104: ('Trap City', 'E District'), 105: ('Trap City', 'S District'), 200: ('Zap City', 'R District'), 201: ('Zap City', 'D District'), 207: ('Los City', 'X District'), 208: ('Los City', 'Y District')}
```

With this new dict you can easily obtain the city and district from a given zipcode.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be done multiple ways, but I made `get_disctrict_and_city()` function which has one parameter `postal_code` and returns tuple with `district` and `city`:

```
zipcode = {"Trap City":{"C District": 100, "D District": 103, "E District": 104, "S District": 105},
       "Zap City":{"R District": 200, "D District": 201},
       "Los City": {"X District": 207, "Y District": 208}}

def get_disctrict_and_city(postal_code, data=zipcode):
    for city, districts in data.items():
        for district, code in districts.items():
            if code == postal_code:
                return district, city

postal_code=int(input('Enter postal code: '))
district, city = get_disctrict_and_city(postal_code)

print('District = {} City = {}'.format(district, city))
```

Output:

```
Enter postal code: 100
District = C District City = Trap City
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about python, But you can google this. I will truy to do it as though you are doing it in R. By googling, i came up with the following:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_city_dist(num,dicts):
    s = pd.DataFrame(dicts)==num
    m = list(s.columns[s.any()]) + list(s.index[s.T.any()])
    return dict(zip(["city","District"], m))


get_dis_cit(103,zipcode)
Out[122]: {'city': 'Trap City', 'District': 'D District'}

get_dis_cit(100,zipcode)
Out[123]: {'city': 'Trap City', 'District': 'C District'}

get_dis_cit(200,zipcode)
Out[124]: {'city': 'Zap City', 'District': 'R District'}

get_dis_cit(208,zipcode)
Out[125]: {'city': 'Los City', 'District': 'Y District'}
```

Comment: Instead of of having nums as argument, you can have it as a user input within the function